# Best Textbook for a Rigorous Treatment of Panel Data

Tags: references, econometrics, panel-data

I was wondering which book you recommend for a treatment of panel data that is both rigorous and intuitive. What do you recommend among Wooldridge(2010), Baltagi(2021), and Hsiao(2022)? I studied static panel data models during my master's classes using Wooldridge. The latest version of Wooldridge is from 2010. Is it still a good choice even though it's a book from 2010?

Comment: Most texts on graduate-level econometrics have decent coverage of panel-data econometrics. Is there something specific you are looking for that would help us help you?

Comment: I was looking for a textbook that covers the latest advances in dynamic panel data analysis and also provides examples. Let's say something tailored for practitioners.

Comment: l'd recommend checking out Hansen's Econometrics volume 2. It's a bit terse but provides a good introduction to dynamic panel data methods.